Ubuntu 24.04 Gdrive hanging
Just upgraded one of my PCs to the new studio 24.04 .
Everything seems to be ok except the gdrive link in Dolphin wasn't working.
I removed and cleared online accounts/google and re signed in, 2step verification etc.
All went well but Dolphin just hangs on  "Loading.." when trying to access the gDrive folder.
thoughts?
